# Redirect to another screen on the second step of the form

Tags: reactjs, forms, redirect, router, multi-step

I have a form in my home page which is InstantQoute. So when the user continues on the form, I want to show the rest of the form in new page. So here is my parent form:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Checkout from "../screens/Checkout";
import InstantQuote from "./InstantQuote";

export class UserForm extends Component {
  state = {
    step: 1,
    zipFrom: "",
    zipTo: "",
    vehicleYear: "",
    vehicleMake: "",
    vehicleModel: "",
  };

  // Proceed to next step
  nextStep = () => {
    const { step } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      step: step + 1,
    });
  };

  // Go back to prev step
  prevStep = () => {
    const { step } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      step: step - 1,
    });
  };

  // Handle fields change
  handleChange = (input) => (e) => {
    this.setState({ [input]: e.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    
    const { step } = this.state;
    const {
      zipFrom,
      zipTo,
      vehicleYear,
      vehicleMake,
      vehicleModel,
    } = this.state;
    const values = {
      zipFrom,
      zipTo,
      vehicleYear,
      vehicleMake,
      vehicleModel,
    };

    switch (step) {
      case 1:
        return (
          <InstantQuote
            nextStep={this.nextStep}
            handleChange={this.handleChange}
            values={values}
          />
        );
      case 2:
        return <Checkout />;
      default:
        return "Unknown step";
    }
  }
}

export default UserForm;
```

So like I said, InstantForm is a form in home page on the header.  is actually a new screen. Like this it actually shows the whole screen inside the header. So could you give me an advice how I can handle the input value and at the same time redirect to another page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ternary operators](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp) to [conditionally render](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) the components. As well, for your `nextStep` and `prevStep` functions, see below implementation, you can read more about this on the official docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#what-does-setstate-do). You can also pass down the state directly as props to your `<InstantQuote />` component since it seems to require most of it, feel free to change this if you wish.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Checkout from "../screens/Checkout";
import InstantQuote from "./InstantQuote";

export class UserForm extends Component {
    state = {
        step: 1,
        zipFrom: "",
        zipTo: "",
        vehicleYear: "",
        vehicleMake: "",
        vehicleModel: "",
    };

    // Proceed to next step
    nextStep = () => this.setState(prevState => ({step: prevState.step + 1}));

    // Go back to prev step
    prevStep = () => this.setState(prevState => ({step: prevState.step - 1}));

    // Handle fields change
    handleChange = (input) => (e) => {
        this.setState({ [input]: e.target.value });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            step == 1 ?
                <InstantQuote
                    nextStep={this.nextStep}
                    handleChange={this.handleChange}
                    values={this.state}
                /> :
                step == 2 ?
                    <Checkout />
                    : <p>Unknown step</p>
        )
    }
}

export default UserForm;
```

Comment: Thanks, thats the answer